# IDA hex != String

Tags: ida, hex

, Hello. to learn reverse engineering, I would like to simply change a string via IDA.
I select my string, get the adress, and select Change Bytes to get the Hex value :

[image]

After That, I try to convert this Hexa value to string, via this website : https://www.mobilefish.com/services/latin_utf_base64_to_hex/latin_utf_base64_to_hex.php#text_hex_output
And the result is not the same,

[image]

Do you known how to get the complete Hex value from my string ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use debugger like `x64dbg` which is far easier than IDA and more suited for this.

Answer (score 1):

where is the problem the hex bytes Were Converted properly
45 00 =E , 6d 00 == m,......73 00 == s
and that is what is shown in your screen shot

if you need the hex for the complete string select all the bytes of the string

try synchronizing between IDA Hex-View and Ida View windows or try clicking the small down arrow to see if all the bytes are shown in the popup

Answer (score 1):

Patch bytes shows only 16 bytes at a time, which is not enough to display the entire string.

Easier to use the Hex Dump view to edit the string. This can be opened with View -> Open Subviews -> Hex Dump. If necessary right click "Synchronize with ..." and specify view to sync with.

You can right click to select option to "Edit..." in this view. Once done editing right click again and you can select option to "Apply Changes" or hit F2.